# How to create a project template node outside Visual C# Project Type Node?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sdk, vsix

Using VSIX project if I do

```
<VSTemplate Include="ProjectTemplate1.vstemplate">

    <OutputSubPath>Sample Test Project</OutputSubPath>

</VSTemplate>
```

the location is
 **\bin\Debug\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Sample Test Project\1033\ProjectTemplate1.zip**

This will create a project template inside Visual C# Template in VS Installed Templates. However, I don't want to have Visual C# as my Project Type Node. It should be outside Visual C# Project Type Node.

How can I achieve this? What changes I need to make and how? Please help

Answer (score 0):

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/04/creating-and-sharing-project-item-templates.aspx,

> The “Type” attribute in the .vstemplate file root node. Project templates go under “ProjectTemplates”. Item templates go under “ItemTemplates”.
>
> The “Language” part of the path (“CSharp” in our example) is determined by the  node in the .vstemplate file.

So, it would appear that you need to create either create a project template from a different type of project, or edit your project template type within the project that you are creating.